# How do I number chapter pages in scrivener?

Tags: non-fiction, scrivener

I do not want numbered lists, I want to number each page of my text. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe Scrivner is just like most programs, in that you want to look at formatting on the header or footer to add page numbers.

Go to Page Settings> Header and Footer tab

There you set what you need. Page numbers should be in there as an option. (there are tons of options--no page number on the first page if you're doing a title page, that sort of thing)

Since I have no idea how you want your pages numbered (settings like centered, to the left, or in the corners of facing pages) I can only point you in the direction of where to start. Good luck! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In **File > Compile > Page settings**, you can set the header using formatting codes found under **Help > Place Holder Tags List**. E.g. `<$p>` will print the page number.

You can also find **Compile** as a shortcut icon in the center of the top frame.

(This is for the Mac version of Scrivener.)

Answer (score 0):

An FYI, for those finding this by a websearch. Page numbers can only be added in the compile phase using the above methods, not when printing off a draft before compilation. Too bad, because it would be handy when running off a copy for your editor to scribble on. If you need to do this, then you have to compile it first and then print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Update for question above. If you are using Scrivener 3 for Windows go to View then text editing and then select page view. If you want to view your page numbers on your print, then do the compile as spoke about from another commenter.